# Find c if $\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \dfrac{c}{x}\right)=0$

Tags: calculus, limits

I tried to apply the limit theorem,

$$\lim _{x\rightarrow x_{0}}cf\left( x\right) =c\lim _{x\rightarrow x_{0}}f\left( x\right) $$
$$\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \dfrac{c}{x}\right) =c\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \dfrac{1}{x}\right)=0 $$
$$c=\dfrac{0}{\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \dfrac{1}{x}\right) }$$
$$c=\dfrac{0}{\infty }$$
I know that $c=0$ satisfies the equation,
$$\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \dfrac{0}{x}\right) =0$$
How do I evaluate for c?

Comment: Show that for any $c \neq 0$, the left hand and the  right hand limits are different.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Although you've already answered your own question, I thought I'd mention one point: $\lim_{x\to a}cf(x)=c\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ doesn't work if $c=0$ and $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ doesn't exist. (Similarly, $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)f(x)=\lim_{x\to a}g(x)\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ only works if all three limits exist and the last two limits' product isn't an indeterminate form such as $0\times\pm\infty$.)

Comment: @J.G. I was wondering why $0\times \lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \dfrac{1}{x}\right) \neq \lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\left( \dfrac{0}{x}\right) $, now I know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $c\in \left( 0,\infty \right) $ ,
$$\lim _{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}\dfrac{c}{x}=\infty $$
$$\lim _{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}\dfrac{c}{x}=-\infty $$
For $c\in \left(-\infty, 0\right) $,
$$\lim _{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}\dfrac{c}{x}=\infty $$
$$\lim _{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}\dfrac{c}{x}=-\infty $$
Hence the limit doesn't exist for $c\neq 0$

Comment: You'll also be able to accept your own answer after a while. Good job and welcome to MSE.